# SignalR 2.X and JQuery 3.X "ON" not fired

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-4, signalr

I'm having issues running SignalR 2.4.1 with any version of JQuery 3.x

I have a very simple hub who sends push notifications to an AngualrJS app. The application works fine with JQuery 1 and 2, but as soon as I upgrade to 3, the SignalR stops working.
I read about the problem with the old load,unload. but that is not the case since it was fixed in 2.2.1

I've got no errors in the console, the angualrJS factory just want get the ON event fired when the notifications comes.

this is the code I use, which is pretty standard and works fine with JQuery < 3

```
function signalRHubProxyFactory(serverUrl, hubName, startOptions) {
        var connection = $.hubConnection(signalRServer);
        var proxy = connection.createHubProxy(hubName);
        connection.start().done(function () { });

        return {
            on: function (eventName, callback) {
                proxy.on(eventName, function (result) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
            off: function (eventName, callback) {
                proxy.off(eventName, function (result) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
            invoke: function (methodName, callback) {
                proxy.invoke(methodName)
                    .done(function (result) {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            if (callback) {
                                callback(result);
                            }
                        });
                    });
            },
            connection: connection
        };
    };

    return signalRHubProxyFactory;
```

Anybody with the same problem?

This is my scripts list

```
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For everybody who had this problem, looks like that in order to make AngularJS, SignalR and JQuery >= 3 work, angular.js script must be added before them all

```
<script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```